# Can able to create same partition name to different tables under same schema in postgressql

Tags: postgresql

Table 1:Partition

**CREATE TABLE p_20230610 PARTITION OF extracharge_data_group
FOR VALUES FROM (1685836800) TO (1686441600)
PARTITION BY LIST (srdg_frag_id);**

In the subsequent line am going to create subpartition also.

Table 2: Partition

**CREATE TABLE p_20230610 PARTITION OF extra_charge
FOR VALUES FROM (1685836800) TO (1686441600)
PARTITION BY LIST (ec_frag_id);**

Error:-

While creating partition for the table 2 , getting the below error

ERROR:  relation "p_20230610" already exists

Currently migrating from oracle to pg, so while creating partition with same name but for different tables having this kind of error.

Comment: Not possible. Use a different name of a different schema.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, a partition is just a regular database table with a “side job” as partition of a partitioned table. In PostgreSQL (like in Oracle) table names must be unique per schema. Consequently, you cannot have two partitions with the same name in the same schema.

You will have to revise your naming schema, for example by starting the partition name with the table name.